# Problem with inserting the symbols \times and \omega when using arabi package

Tags: symbols, greek, arabic, persian

Is it impossible to insert the mathematical symbol `\times` when using the `arabi` package?

After compiling

```
A\times B
```

it becomes `AB` and the sign `\times` disappears

See the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi} 
سلام   
$A\times B$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know whether this fact is documented (I can't see it in the manual, though), but the `arabicfnt.sty` that's automatically loaded has

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\times}{\fontfamily{artimes}\selectfont}
```

which explains the mystery.

You can solve the problem by adding to your document

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mtimes}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"02}
```

and using `\mtimes` for the product symbol. If you want to use `\times` for the symbol, you have to rename the font changing command (or leave it out altogether):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\timesr}{\fontfamily{artimes}\selectfont}
\let\times\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\times}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"02}
```

Note that a similar problem happens for `\omega`, so either you do

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\momega}{\mathord}{letters}{"21}
```

and use `\momega` for the Greek letter, or rename the font command

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\omegar}{\fontfamily{aromega}\selectfont}
\let\omega\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{letters}{"21}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I confirm that your solution perfectly works.

Comment: I am interested to know from where the numbers 21 and 02 in your answer comes. And if there is a comprehensive list of such numbers, I would be glad to know about it.

Comment: @Name You can find them reading the file `fontmath.ltx`

Comment: Perfect as usual. Why is there nothing to see with \times or \omega? What's the purpose of the commands in arabicfnt.sty?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The commands are redefined as font selection commands; not a good choice, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg I see. Here would  a package specific and unique prefix or something similar help :). Thanks for the reply.