# Problem with inserting the Greek letter \omega when using Arabi package

Tags: greek, arabic, persian

In the following example, the symbol \omega does not show up after compiling the file. This is the first Greek later for which I have this kind of the problem.
Is there a way to solve this problem. This question is related to my previous question in
[Problem with inserting the symbols \times and \omega when using arabi package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207232/problem-with-inserting-the-symbol-times-when-using-arabi-package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi} 
$\omega$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207232/problem-with-inserting-the-symbol-times-when-using-arabi-package; I'll add the workaround for `\omega` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again there seems to be something being redefined. A simple solution is to define your own command, in this case `\myomega`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}
\mathchardef\myomega="0121

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi} 
$\myomega$ 
\end{document}
```