# PDFlatex : Some Greek letters disappear from PDF when babel package is used

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, babel

I have a problem with **Greek letters** in math mode. Some letters disappear from PDF file when **babel** package is used  I'm using **pdflatex** engine. and here are two minimal codes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \omega  \quad \alpha
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

this code create the following pdf :

[image]

but when **babel** package is used some letters disappear and here the other code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \omega  \quad \alpha
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

this code create the following pdf :

[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem with out changing the **pdflatex** engine ?

Comment: For some unknown reason arabic redefines the \omega (and \times) and maps them to a font which isn't in the package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207236/2388.